# Is colorized subpixel rendering possible?

Tags: color, subpixel-rendering

Subpixel rendering is used most commonly to anti alias fonts. It works by leveraging the physical layout of the color components of a display to give geometry details to an image that are smaller than a pixel.

For instance, this font has a height of 3 pixels but can easily be read:
[image]

from: http://www.sitepoint.com/two-teeny-tiny-fonts/

This is a monochromatic case, and i could see this possibly working in a greyscale case, but it seems like it always has to be used in situations where you have high contrast.

Is it possible to use sub pixel rendering in a full color situation, such as those you'd find while doing a 3d render of a scene?

I think that it must not be, since it won't be high contrast enough, but does anyone have examples to the contrary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of a downsampling filter that takes pixel geometry into account: [Increasing image resolution on portable displays by subpixel rendering](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S2048770312000030).

Image (a) below is an image downsampled using pixel-based downsampling. Image (b) is downsampled using direct subpixel-based downsampling, which (as far as I can tell) effectively downsamples the R, G, and B planes of the image independently. Image (c) is downsampled using diagonal direct subpixel-based downsampling, which uses a diagonal pattern to improve apparent resolution in both horizontal and vertical directions.

[image: Figure 11 from the paper]

You can see that the last two images look sharper, but also have the characteristic color fringing.

Here's the downsampling pattern used for the last image:

[image: DDSD downsampling pattern]

Comment: By displaying the images magnified, you entirely negate the benefit of using subpixels, so the comparison images aren't representative of the actual results. You should try posting the original-size images if possible.

Comment: @yuriks There's another smaller resolution that I can find (http://journals.cambridge.org/fulltext_content/SIP/SIP1/S2048770312000030_fig11p.jpeg) but it's not immediately apparent to me that that version is not minified or magnified. I do think it's educational to see the magnified version, since it lets you see the fringing and doesn't actually get rid of the sharpness relative to the regular downsampling.

Comment: @yuriks, problem with these kinds of images are that not all monitors have same subpixel sequence. And on mobile devices the orientation needs to change when the user turns the device.